# Firefox seems to be caching js files differently from other types

Tags: firefox, http, javascript, cache

I am developing a web page and Firefox just showed me some weird behaviour

- Changes to html and css appear instantly in the browser
- Changes to js seems to be cached
- if I `curl 'http://localhost/static/script.js'` then I see the latest version
- if I open the Web Developer Tools in Firefox, then in the "response" section of the "Network" tab shows the *old* content
- if I `copy as cURL` the request for `script.js` and paste into a terminal, curl gives me the new version (this tells me that request headers are not interfering) but refreshing the browser again yields the old content
- after a while, for no particular reason, the new content makes its way though to the browser

The behaviour of `curl` (even when reproducing Firefox's request) assures me the content from the server is correct, so Firefox is over-caching this script.

How can I make it stop?

Comment: turn off caching

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you have already in `about:config` disabled
"browser.cache.disk.enable" and
"widget.clipboard.use-cached-data.enabled",
or that in Dev tools (F12) you have already set *Network > Disable cache*.

You could try the extension
[No-Cache No-Store for Selected Hosts](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/no-cache-no-store-for-css/) :

> Reloading doesn't update your CSS any more? Bypass Firefox's aggressive caching of CSS (and optionally other content) during development. Use the button on the Page Actions menu to grant new host permissions for blocking.

Comment: "Disable cache" in dev tools fixed it, thanks.